# C++ Comparing the length of two similar arrays

Tags: c++

I believe Array1 and Array2 are declared differently but they both do have the same type - char. Both Array1 and Array2 seem to contain the same exact values and the same amount of values. I don't understand why their length are different from each other. Can someone please explain why?

```
char Array1[ ] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
char Array2[ ] = "\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05";

std::cout << "Length of Array1 = " << sizeof( Array1 )/sizeof( *Array1 )
          << std::endl
          << "Length of Array2 = " << sizeof( Array2 )/sizeof( *Array2 );
```

Output:

```
Length of Array1 = 5
Length of Array2 = 6
```

Comment: The second array is initialized with a string literal which contains an implicit `\0` at the end.

Comment: /Face-palm I can't believe I forgot about that! @sgar91 Well, that explains everything.

Comment: @PlasmaHH How it could be duplicate if he does not asks what is NT? =)

Comment: I have flagged this post. The answer is because it was null terminated! It was simple as that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second array has an extra character due to the implicit null terminating character present in the string literal.

From section *2.14.5 String literals* of the C++11 standard (draft n3337) point 14 states:

> After any necessary concatenation, in translation phase 7 (2.2), **’\0’ is appended to every string literal** so
>   that programs that scan a string can find its end.

Comment: Can't believe I've forgot about the null terminating character. Thanks. +1

Comment: I will accept this answer in 7 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

Because strings a NULL-treminated. You have extra character at string literal '\0'